# i cant parse the json data

Tags: php, android, json

here this code was working and then suddenly after another test it didtn work and said that the json contains html elements like 
 and i cant make it work again i need help

```
<?php

include("config.php");

if(isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
}   

$con = mysqli_connect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME);

$response = array();

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ? OR username = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $email, $username);
$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
$rows = $result->num_rows;

if($rows > 0){
    $response["success"] = false;
    $response["message"] = "Email or Username already exists.";
}else{
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
    $statement2 = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO accounts (email, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement2, "sss", $email, $username, $password);
    $result2 = mysqli_stmt_execute($statement2);
    $rows2 = $result2->affected_rows;

    if($rows2 > 0){
        $response["success"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "Account created successfuly.";
    }else{
        $response["success"] = false;
        $response["message"] = "Creation error.";
    }
}

echo json_encode($response);

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

when i parse it in andoid it says to me that it contains a something thas is no a string .. and this is my android code for parsing the json

```
private void register() {
        Response.Listener<String> responselistener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonresponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean success = jsonresponse.getBoolean("success");
                    String message = jsonresponse.get("message").toString();
                    if(success){
                        Intent gotoContinueRegisterActivityIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, ContinueRegisterActivity.class);
                        startActivity(gotoContinueRegisterActivityIntent);
                    }else {
                        error.setText(message);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error2) {
                error2.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(s_email, s_username, s_password, responselistener, errorListener);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getBaseContext());
        requestQueue.add(registerRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Try sending a `json` header -> `header("Content-Type: application/json");`

Comment: how can u show me please ?

Comment: Just did..... put that `header(...)` at the beginning of your php script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're best to actually send headers to let your android app know that it's receiving `json` as it probably thinks it's getting the Content Type: `text/html`.

Try placing this header at the top of your PHP script:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```